# Wifi download speed very low on laptop but not desktop

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

I have a desktop PC and a laptop PC connected to the same router over wifi. Download speeds on the former are ~40Mbps but on the latter are ~17Mbps. Upload speeds on both PCs are the same at ~12Mbps. The router is a 802.11n device. The desktop is using an 802.11n USB adapter. The laptop has a newer built in 802.11ac adapter.

- Router model: Linksys E1200 v2
- Desktop USB adapter: Realtek RTL8188EU Wireless LAN 802.11n USB 2.0 Network Adapter
- Laptop built in adapter: Qualcomm Atheros QCA61x4A Wireless Network Adapter

Both PCs have Windows 10 installed. They and a Roku stick are the only devices connected to the router. I have tried connecting only the laptop and not the others with no positive results.

I think the problems on my laptop started when I "tested" the USB adapter by plugging it into the laptop, which was probably not a smart thing to do.

How do I diagnose and resolve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: On the laptop, run TCP/IP Reset, DNS Flush, restart and test.  Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
Then: netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
Then: ipconfig /flushdns
Then: restart the computer

Comment: One of the steps failed with "access denied" when executing `netsh`. There is no log file on C however.

Comment: On the problem machine, you may now need to do a Windows 10 Repair Install. This will repair Windows 10 and update all drivers as it repairs. Use the option to Keep Everything for the first time.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: Lots of people are having issues with your adapter. Have you tried the latest drivers from your laptop manufacturer or Atheros?

Comment: I did the repair install with no luck. The laptop is an Acer SP314-51. The driver version from the Acer support site is actually older than than the one Microsoft recommends. I tried both drivers and no change. I may try a hard wipe and reinstall of Windows 10.

Comment: I am seeing reports that some driver versions work better than others. Not sure which driver versions to roll back to though.

Comment: Try this driver: https://www.dell.com/support/home/ng/en/ngbsdt1/drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=9H7GC  Some people have reported success with it.

Comment: I suggest trying a different USB adapter (not the existing one for your Desktop) on the laptop to see if the issue is related only to the laptop

Comment: @Natsu Kage - Windows did not let me install that driver, saying it already had the best driver. I was not able to uninstall the default driver either.

Comment: @John - The only other adapters I have are b/g adapters. Is that okay?

Comment: b/g adapters are not very fast. Try and see if your speed improves. But you may need to get a faster USB adapter.

Comment: I moved my laptop right next to my router and download speeds improved to about ~30Mbps. Still much less than my desktop however.

Comment: I tried connecting to a b/g router I had lying around, but am the rated speeds for this device are so low I'm not sure how to interpret the results. (Speeds are roughly the same as I reported above.)